# determine biggest variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have the following variables:

```
int currentCreated = 94.6;
int averageCreated = 80.1;
int currentAssigned = 78.9;
int averageAssigned = 81.3;
```

How would one determine the biggest variable? I mean, I can easily do the number itself with Math.max, but I'm interested in the biggest value *and* variable name.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not JavaScript. Getting the variable name would only be possible (and even then a bit tricky, or at least annoying to do) if they were global variables. I would use a hash map (aka object) to store the name + value.

Comment: You want to measure which variable name has the most chars?

Comment: He seems to want to scan the global/current scope for all variables, determine the one with the largest number in it, and retrieve both the variable name and the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check value and the actual name itself, your best bet may be to use an associative array or an object and check the length of the keys, and their values. I cannot immediately think of any other way to accomplish this.

Example:

```
var numbers = {
  currentCreated:  94.6,
  averageCreated:  80.1,
  currentAssigned: 78.9,
  averageAssigned: 81.3
};

for ( e in numbers ) 
  console.log( e.length + ' ' + numbers[e] );
```

Comment: I think he wants to finds the highest value, not the longest name. But anyway, an object is the way to go.

Comment: @Felix I thought the same, but he did say 'biggest value *and variable name*.'

Comment: Ah yes, it could also be understood this way... but I think he just wants to get the name.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, just for entertainment.

```
function max(context){
    var m = Math.max.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)),
        n = null;

    Object.keys( context ).some(function( prop ) {
        if( window[prop] === m ) {
            n = prop; return true;
        }

         return false;
    });


    return [n,m];
}

var foo = 5,
    bar = 11,
    baz = -2;

max(this, foo,bar,baz); // ['bar', 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's very late to answer this question, but just in case if this is helpful to someone in the future, I'd like to share a solution I found recently while working on a similar scenario:

```
var age1 = 32,
    age2 = 24,
    age3 = 34,
    age4 = 19;

var ages = [age1, age2, age3, age4],
    maxAge = Math.max.apply(Math.max, ages),
    ageNames = ["age1", "age2", "age3", "age4"],
    maxAgeName = ageNames[ages.indexOf(maxAge)];
```

I know, the variable names could be better, but this is just for illustration.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(currentCreated>averageCreated && currentCreated>currentAssigned && currentAssigned>averageAssigned){//currentCreated is biggest}
```

Do that for each one and voila!